# How can I encrypt a string with Triple DES and output format of base64

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, base64, tripledes

I'm trying to get some help regarding encoding with Triple DES in python.
I want to have 2 functions: encode/decode
and I want it to operate as it does on the site: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/triple-des-encrypt-decrypt, with the base64 output format.
because when I decode that base64 msg I get some random chars and that's what I want.
I've tried doing that with pycryptodome but it gives me a byte output.

what I've tried:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

# Avoid Option 3
while True:
    try:
        key = DES3.adjust_key_parity(get_random_bytes(24))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
plaintext = b'We are no longer the knights who say ni!'
msg = cipher.iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
```

How would I be able to do that? any help would be appreciated!
Or maybe do you know what most programs use to encrypt their files? for example word.

Comment: Updated. well that's the output I want I'm not really trying to understand deeply how to encrypt strings I have 1 case I need to use that encryption, so I'm trying to get simple instructions and maybe a brief explanation.

Comment: You are trying to do two things; encrypt and then convert the encrypted text to base64.  I suggest that you try doing just the base64 conversion first since that is easier.  When you have that working correctly then try the encryption part.  Post your code here if you have problems.

Comment: rossum, I've already managed to encrypt to base64 and to Triple DES, but i want to encrypt it the way https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/triple-des-encrypt-decrypt did it.

Comment: They don't specify how they did it, but ECB doesn't use an IV, so you could start by removing that. And of course they don't use a random IV, instead they seem to use an ASCII encoding or something similar (i.e. it isn't really a key in the first place, see what I mean with "clueless"?).